# Query to correctly sort the years when using DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

I have a Yii model that I am using to return the following sql query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.year_id
FROM
`myuser` `t`
INNER JOIN organisation o ON (t.organisation_id = o.organisation_id)
WHERE o.organisation_id = 12345
ORDER BY t.year_id ASC
```

This returns the following:

```
year_id
  10
  15
  2
  7
  9
```

How do I change this so it displays this in the order 2, 7, 9, 10, 15 instead? Note - The row is a varchar data type as it does have some strings e.g Nursery, Reception etc..

Comment: `ORDER BY convert(t.year_id, decimal)`  Assuming year is varchar

Comment: what is the format of the year_id field in the db? If it's not a number format but a text one then you will get this as the corret ascending order. The order will be made char by char and 1 comes before 2. A numeric field will understand that 10 is greater than 2

Comment: But why varchar??? Use integer and the problem is gone!

Comment: What do you mean with "The row is a varchar data type as it does have some strings e.g Nursery, Reception etc.."?

Comment: I know.. this was an integer but our client requested to use strings (I advised him against this)

Comment: @Mihai that works, please submit that as an answer & i'll accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert it to number,as a VARCHAR it is ordered lexicographical

```
ORDER BY convert(t.year_id, decimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(t.year_id,UNSIGNED INTEGER) ASC
```